# How to get faster SELECT indexes?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

Here is the structure of my table.

```
create table bids
(
    id           int unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    user_id      int unsigned                        not null,
    shipment_id  int unsigned                        not null,
    amount       double(8, 2)                        not null,
    commission   double(8, 2)                        not null,
    invoice_id   int unsigned                        null,
    created_at   timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    accepted_at  timestamp                           null,
    retracted_at timestamp                           null
)
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create index bids_shipment_id_index
    on bids (shipment_id);

create index bids_user_id_index
    on bids (user_id);

create index bids_user_id_shipment_id_index
    on bids (user_id, shipment_id)
```

Table has about 60M rows

Running a simple query as that: `SELECT * FROM bids WHERE user_id = 3344;` takes about 2s.

**How can I make this query run even faster?**

Comment: You already have an index on `user_id`, so nothing more you can do. --- Note that index `bids_user_id_index` is redundant, since the 2-column index `bids_user_id_shipment_id_index` starts with `user_id`, so you should remove index `bids_user_id_index` to improve insert performance.

Comment: Do **not** post images of tables. Post the `CREATE TABLE` and in this case also the `CREATE INDEX` statements as **text**.

Comment: You can try [OPTIMIZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html). Of this is successful mainly depends on the fragmentation of the table that is queried.

Comment: Which Engine is the table using?

Comment: @RickJames InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas commented above, you already have at least two indexes that *might* help, if the indexes are used by the query.

You should confirm the optimizer is choosing an index for your query, using `EXPLAIN`. It's possible the optimizer is refusing to use the index for some reason. For example, if user_id 3344 occurs on a large number of rows, the optimizer may decide the index is not going to safe any work.

For the same reason common words like *"the"* are not included in the index at the back of a book. It would be a waste of time to look up a common word in a book's index, because it'll just tell you that the word occurs on most pages of the book. It would be easier to just read every page of the book, cover to cover.

You haven't shared any details about your MySQL Server tuning options. It's possible you have an undersized innodb buffer pool, and the query is doing too much reading from disk, and then evicting pages from the buffer pool, over and over. You should size your buffer pool proportional to the dataset. A good starting place that I use for many apps is a ratio of 1:10 between buffer pool and data size on disk.

Check the buffer pool size: `SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;`

Check the data size: `SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE ENGINE='InnoDB';`

You haven't described the server specifications. Do you have an underpowered server for this scale of data? Do you use old-school spinning disks, or SSD storage? Is the data stored on a remote volume like NFS or if it's in AWS, is it EBS? Remote volumes are bound to be a lot slower. Use locally-attached high-speed storage.

You haven't described what else is running on your database server. Is the server also running demanding applications? A good way to improve performance is to run the database on a dedicated server, with no other databases or applications competing for resources.